# Difference between .ActiveControl and .Focus and what each does

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I am a currently learning C# and added this to my code

```
InitializeComponent();
this.ActiveControl = txtUsername;
txtUsername.Focus();
```

What does do and what does `this.ActiveControl` `.Focus`do and whats the difference

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can both do the same thing effectively.  One requires a visible element while the other does not. This can be used to place cursor input on `txtUsername` when the form appears.

```
this.ActiveControl = txtUsername;
```

This will do the same thing if the `txtUsername` control is visible.

```
txtUsername.Focus();
```

The key is that the element must be visible in order for the `Focus()` method to work.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6597196/2348184) for further information.