# Not able to set TextBox as focused

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows Forms application, that has a TextBox `tbID`

```
tbID.Enabled = true;
tbID.Visible = true;
tbID.Focus();
Log("tbID focused : {0}", tbID.Focused);
```

I want to set the TextBox to focussed. I am setting it in the above line. It doesn't seem to work. From [CanFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.canfocus?view=net-5.0) I found that you need to set both `Enabled` and `Visible` to true before setting `Focus`
to true.

But even `Visible` is showing as `false` even after setting it to `true`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to put focus on TextBox when the form load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597196/how-to-put-focus-on-textbox-when-the-form-load)

Comment: Is `TextBox.Visible = false` or `TextBox.Enabled = false` set in the designer? In this case, why? Or, can it become disabled/invisible at run-time for some reason? In any case, in what context are you try to focus it? Where / when is this code run?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `tbID.InvokeRequired`. If the value is true then try to make call cross-thread controls in a thread-safe way.

[Make thread safe calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

[Invoke required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired?view=net-5.0)